# Nest of intervals explanation

Tags: analysis

I am currently reading Konrad Knopp book about infinite series, I just don't get the part where he mentions that the nest of intervals would determine or define as he said a rational number s if it exists(I am still on page 24 he is still constructing irrational numbers).Could anyone please explain that part.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that what you mean is that every non-increasing sequence of intervals for which the length converges to zero defines a unique *real* number $s$. This is a kind of hybrid of the Dedekind and Cantor (Cauchy sequence) constructions for the real numbers in terms of the rational numbers.

The way you have to think about this is that real numbers are not yet defined. All you have is the rational numbers. The task is to define real numbers somehow using only rational numbers. In your case, you use sequences of intervals to define the real numbers, but of course the end-points of those intervals must be rational numbers because the real numbers are not yet defined!

The point of the method is that it can be shown that all of the properties of real numbers can be proved from equivalence classes of these nests of intervals. The full technicalities of constructing real numbers from rational numbers are actually quite burdensome. The main idea here is to build up a picture in your mind of how real numbers can be defined using just rational numbers. The motivation for this comes from certain philosophical issues which arose at the end of the 19th century.

Comment: Thanks now I can see why that makes sense.

Comment: Perhaps I could also mention that various paradoxes regarding the real numbers near the end of the 19th century caused mathematicians to try to define real numbers in terms of rational numbers because the rationals were thought to be logically more secure. Some of the first attempts were actually circular because they implicitly used real numbers to define real numbers. It took a while to show that you could construct real numbers without assuming that they exist already. So that's why real numbers are constructed very carefully now. Intuition is not trusted any more!